# Variable variables in Twig

Tags: templating, php, variable, set

I'd like to create a variable from another variable. What I got right now is something like this:

```
{% set language = fr %} 
{% if language == "en"  %}
   {% set fooAddress = en_foobar.globalAddress %} 
{% if language == "fr"  %}
   {% set fooAddress = fr_foobar.globalAddress %}
{% if language == "de"  %}
   {% set fooAddress = de_foobar.globalAddress %}
```

What I'd like to do is:

```
{% set fooAddress = language  ~ "_foobar.globalAddress" %}
```

No problem with plain PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) but is this possible to do with Twig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to pull this off, you'll need to take advantage of the not very well  [documented](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) `_context` variable in Twig.  This should do it:

```
{% set language = 'fr' %}

{% set foobar = _context[language ~ "_foobar"] is defined ? _context[language ~ "_foobar"] : null %}

{% if foobar %}
    {{ foobar.globalAddress }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: tried it that way, but i get this in response:
Impossible to access an attribute ("globalAddress") on a string variable ("fr_foobar")

Comment: Updated the answer and actually tested this one. :)

Comment: `_context` documentation, such as it is, is here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

Comment: @BradBell ...and I had hoped to see the first example where the `attribute` function works `attribute(foo, bar)` and the subscript syntax `foo[bar]` doesn't.

Comment: @MarionNewlevant nice... linked to it.

Comment: @carlcs yeah, tried several variations using `attribute` and couldn't get anything to work.